# Testing Rails helper that uses html escaping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

I'm attempting test a helper in Rails 4 that calls `h(some_content)` but when I run my unit tests I receive: `undefined method 'h' for PageHelperTest`.

How can I call `h` inside my helper, but still be able to execute the code in test? The code works correctly when hit through the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `h` method is defined on `ERB::Util` which isn't available in the helper test. I fixed the issue by changing the helper to call `ERB::Util.h(some_content)`

Answer (score 0):

Well I just hit similar issue.
However changing the helper just for the tests to pass is a NO NO to me.

So I tried around and this solved it (HOWEVER in Rails 3.2.22):

`include ERB::Util
alias_method :html_escape, :h`

I guess it's not the cleanest way (the alias, and what if another helper needs some other thing). So I guess there would be some better way (include some group of modules or whatnot) - but this one works.